# Storm Topology not working

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-storm

I am new to storm but still i have configured storm on my local machine. I made an eclipse project and followed a simple example from internet. Now my topology is getting submitted but its not working.

Was topology submitted?
  Yeah it was submitted successfully as I can see it on storm ui.

Work of my topology is to just print a number if it is a prime number. But its not printing it.

I have provided my code as follows:

**Spout Class:**

```
public class NumberSpout extends BaseRichSpout 
{
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SpoutOutputCollector.class);
    private static int currentNumber = 1;

    @Override
    public void open( Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector ) 
    {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() 
    {
        // Emit the next number
        LOGGER.info("Coming in spout tuble method");
        collector.emit( new Values( new Integer( currentNumber++ ) ) );
    }

    @Override
    public void ack(Object id) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void fail(Object id) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) 
    {
        declarer.declare( new Fields( "number" ) );
    }
}
```

**Bolt Class:**

```
public class PrimeNumberBolt extends BaseRichBolt 
{   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PrimeNumberBolt.class);
    private OutputCollector collector;

    public void prepare( Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector ) 
    {
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    public void execute( Tuple tuple ) 
    {
        int number = tuple.getInteger( 0 );
        if( isPrime( number) )
        {
            LOGGER.info("Prime number printed is: )" +number);
           System.out.println( number );
        }
        collector.ack( tuple );
    }

    public void declareOutputFields( OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer ) 
    {
        declarer.declare( new Fields( "number" ) );
    }   

    private boolean isPrime( int n ) 
    {
        if( n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3 )
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Is n an even number?
        if( n % 2 == 0 )
        {
            return false;
        }

        //if not, then just check the odds
        for( int i=3; i*i<=n; i+=2 ) 
        {
            if( n % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Topology Class:**

```
public class PrimeNumberTopology 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout( "spout", new NumberSpout(),1 );
        builder.setBolt( "prime", new PrimeNumberBolt(),1 )
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "127.0.0.1");
        conf.setDebug(true);
        Map storm_conf = Utils.readStormConfig();
        storm_conf.put("nimbus.host", "127.0.0.1");
        Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(storm_conf)
                .getClient();
        String inputJar = "/home/jamil/Downloads/storm-twitter-word-count-master/target/storm-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar";
        NimbusClient nimbus = new NimbusClient("127.0.0.1",6627);
        // upload topology jar to Cluster using StormSubmitter
        String uploadedJarLocation = StormSubmitter.submitJar(storm_conf,
                inputJar);
        try {
            String jsonConf = JSONValue.toJSONString(storm_conf);
            nimbus.getClient().submitTopology("newtesttopology",
                    uploadedJarLocation, jsonConf, builder.createTopology());
        } catch (AlreadyAliveException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidTopologyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to ask that why its not printing? Or why its not writing it to log files?

**PLUS:** I am submitting topology from eclipse.

Comment: Where do you expect this to be printed? System prints are never redirected to log files.

Comment: I am logging them as well using log4j logger.

Comment: So how did you configured log4j then?

Comment: I did not configured log4j for this project.

Comment: I placed log4j properties file in project as well . But its still not logging.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what `@Thomas Jungblut` said (regarding your log4j configuration) and assuming that is the complete source code of your topology, then have a look at your `nextTuple()` method of your spout.
Your spout is simply emitting one value and thats it. Great chances that you are missing the output of that emitting in your console because it is buried under a ton of other logging outputs.
Are you sure that you want to emit just one value?